# How to Call a variable from one controller to another controller with out using scope

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularjs,
i have one problem quick replies appreciated. 
I Need a variable from one controller to another controller 
i don't want to use scope. or Service 
how can i do that?

Comment: By using `window` object.

Comment: can you please clear?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken to implementing models to achieve this kind of functionality.  Most commonly I use this to make data sets returned by a web service accessible by multiple screens.

Ex:  Say you have an "Accounts" screen that displays course grain information on all accounts but you also want to offer an "Account Details" screen that shows finer grained information.  Assuming your collection of accounts contains detailed account information there's no need to suffer an additional web service call from the details screen; merely make the data accessible via a model.

I know its not the best example but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in first controller. You need to inject [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service in your controllers.

> A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally
>   available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is
>   a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the
>   $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for
>   testing.

```
app.controller("FirstController", ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) { 
$window.my_value = "value";
}]);
```

And you will get this value in second controller, like

```
app.controller("SecondController", ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) { 
    console.log($window.my_value);
    }]);
```